# iPhone - Tweak the UINavigationController to show a UINavigationBar made into IB

Tags: iphone, interface-builder, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I've build a UINavigationBar into Interface Builder, and I have a NavigationController into my app. I'd like to make the one use the other to work. Just to manage the bar into IB and let the controller use it as its view (and adding by itself the Back button if needed), or in another way to do the same thing, let the NavBar use the navcontroller to adjust its display.

Do you see a way to do this ?

If not, I really don't see the use of the NavigationBar proposed into IB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create the view controller in IB, you can give it a navigation item (UINavigationItem), and put your buttons in there. If you only create the view in IB and the controller is the owner (you use initWithNibName:bundle:), then you will either have to create the items programatically or put a outlet named navigationItem in your custom controller and connect it to a navigation item in the nib.